# How to alert $.ajax get data which contain date

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datetime, asp.net-ajax

this is my controller action. holiDays variable contains array of DateTime like(21/03/2015 12:00:00 AM) which I passed by Json to the view:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetHolydays()
    {
        var holiDays = DbFactory.Db.YearHolydays.ToList();
        return Json(new {con = holiDay},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and this is my jquery codes,which gets data via ajax request:

```
<script>
scheduler.attachEvent("onSchedulerReady", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Customer/Customer/GetHolydays",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(obj.cenas);
            scheduler.blockTime(new Date(), "fullday");
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to alert returned data, but that does not work for me and alert does not show data.

Comment: You have set the `dataType` property to `json`. jQuery parses the response. `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` line is redundant.

Comment: thanke@Vohuman,I removed var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); and changed alert to this  alert(data.cenas); and alert said undefined and also I have tried  this  alert(data); it said [object Object].

Comment: Use `console.log` for debugging instead of the `alert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data must be in Json format.

....

```
 success: function (data) {
        alert(data);// It must be a json
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(obj.cenas);
        scheduler.blockTime(new Date(),"fullday");
    },
```

...

Comment: actually data does not need to --> jQuery.parseJSON(data); instead --> new Date(parseInt(obj.Date.substring(6))) will omit --> /Date(  part of JSon --> /Date(1234567890)/ and  ignore --> )/   then parseInt convert 1234567890 into standard dateTime format.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all did it and here is the code:

```
 success: function (data) {

                var obj = data.con;

                console.log(new Date(parseInt(obj.Date.substring(6))));//I did this 
                console.log(obj.HollidayDescription);

        },
```